# UWP Add animation on ItemsControl items

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp

[image]

Up there is my mock up animation on a static Page in UWP.
And here's the mock up XAML code

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="GridViewButtonPointerEnteredAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewButtonBackdrop">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="100">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="GridViewButtonPointerExitAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewButtonBackdrop">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="40">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="286" Height="286">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/home/home_mydesk.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>

            <Border x:Name="GridViewButtonBackdrop" Background="Transparent" />

            <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/boxfade.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Border.Background>

                <StackPanel Margin="20,20">
                    <TextBlock Text="My Desk" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxHeight="40" />

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/pdf_16.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="PDF File" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerEnteredAnimation}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerExitAnimation}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So I implemented that on my ItemsControl.ItemTemplate. I ran the application, but when I hover into an item, an error spits out and it said.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: No installed components were detected.

Cannot resolve TargetName GridViewButtonBackdrop.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.Begin()
   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media.ControlStoryboardAction.Execute(Object sender, Object parameter)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.Interaction.ExecuteActions(Object sender, ActionCollection actions, Object parameter)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior.OnEvent(Object sender, Objec
```

Here's the XAML implementation for ItemsControl.ItemTemplate.DataTemplate

```
<Grid Width="286" Height="286" Background="{StaticResource DefaultThemeColor}">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icon_pdf.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsPDF},ConverterParameter=pdf}"/>
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/interactive_placeholder.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"  Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsPDF}, ConverterParameter=interactive}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding image.data.full_path}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Grid>

    <Border x:Name="GridViewButtonBackdrop" Background="Transparent" />

    <Border MinHeight="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/boxfade.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Border.Background>

        <StackPanel Margin="20,20">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding info.data.description}" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" MaxHeight="40" />

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsPDF},ConverterParameter=pdf}">
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/pdf_16.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="PDF File" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource IsPDF}, ConverterParameter=interactive}">
                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icon_interactive.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="Interactive" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerEnteredAnimation}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
            <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerExitAnimation}"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

I understand that it may not be seeing that **GridViewButtonBackdrop** element because it was inside an item collection.

**How do I properly implement this animation in my ItemsControl items?**

-- UPDATE --

Thanks for the optimization tip @JustinXL. I will change the ItemsControl into ListView and optimize the animation.

So here it is now
[image]

XAML

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="GridViewButtonPointerEnteredAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewButtonBackdrop">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Description">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="115"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextDescription">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0.0001">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="43">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Name="GridViewButtonPointerExitAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="GridViewButtonBackdrop">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Description">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="115">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="TextDescription">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="286" Height="286">
            <Grid.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,286,286" />
            </Grid.Clip>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/home/home_mydesk.jpg"/>
            </Grid.Background>

            <Border x:Name="GridViewButtonBackdrop" Background="#AF000000" Opacity="0" />

            <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="150">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/boxfade.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>

            <Border x:Name="Description" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateY="115"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel Margin="20,20">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="My Desk" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextDescription" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxHeight="43" Margin="0,5,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  />

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,8,0,0">
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/pdf_16.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="PDF File" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextDescriptionExpanded" Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxHeight="100" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerEnteredAnimation}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource GridViewButtonPointerExitAnimation}"/>
                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I made a UserControl instead and the animation worked.. But I think this will hurt some low end devices. StoryBoard on each item in ItemsControl? My application may have more than 10 or 50 items in Itemscontrol and each of the item will have StoryBoard in it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, wrapping it inside a `UserControl` shouldn't impact the overall performance. That's actually how I would implement it. If you want further optimization, consider replacing your `ItemsControl` with a `ListView` which gives you UI virtualization (i.g. it only renders what you see plus a bit more) by default.

However, what would hurt the performance much more is that you are animating the `MaxHeight` property that could cause layout updates. This type of animations is called *dependent* animation which runs on the UI thread. Try to avoid them as much as you can.

So here's a simple workaround -

1. Duplicate the text, make the duplicated one span more lines and push it down to align with the original by changing its `TranslateY`, then hide it by default.
2. When hovering over, hide the original and show the duplicated and then animate its `TranslateY` to bring it up.

Note that `TranslateY` is part of the `CompositeTransform` which won't cause any costly layout updates.

Comment: good stuff! I had another idea with the animation then. You know your XAML very well :) Thanks!